# How to Solve this challenge

Tags: c++

I have a circle with points 0-360 the first and last point are connected, take point 11 and 216. Now, give any point how can i find if it is close to 11 or 216. I need a generic algorithm. For example:if given point 20 it should find that its close to 11, and when given 200 it should find close to 216. Till this point its easy but, for point 350 it should find that its close to 11, not 216.
I have this formula but it don't work for the third case:

```
 int find_point(int a){
   int temp1=(a>=11?a-11:11-a);
   int temp2=(a>=216?a-216:216-a);
   if(temp1<temp2)
     return 11;
   else
     return 216;
}
```

Comment: Maybe, it's worth to check `a + 360` and `a - 360` as well.

Comment: "The third case"? I suggest you solve a simpler problem first: find the distance between two given points. So f(15,20)=5, f(20,15)=5, f(200,10)=170. Once you have that working, this problem will be easy.

Comment: And f(355,5) = 10?

Comment: @stark can you elaborate how can i implement it because simple finding absolute distance will give 350.

Comment: @Jarod42 I missed the trick with the curly braces (and wondered why there isn't a version with parameter pack). I will fix this.

Comment: BTW, which language are you programming in, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  The C++ has an algorithms library which may have some functions that you can use.  Also, in C you can name a function "class" with no conflicts.  You should decide on the single language and update your tags.  Mixing the languages adds more complexity to your project.

Comment: Do you have x,y coordinates of points or all what you have is point index in array?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas i had point indexes in array.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It wasn't about writing the code but i wanted to crack the logic. I wasn't able to consider the fact that point 0 and 360 are connected and that piont 300 is closer to 11 than 216.  Any way, I am programming in C++.

Comment: @letsShareKnowlede Then it's a matter of defining correct distance function between points, which is : `distance(a,b)=min(|a-b|,360-|a-b|)`

Comment: If you are programming in C++, why the C language tag?  You should edit your language tags to show the language you are programming in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the trick with the circle – it's round.

So, there are always two ways to get from one point on a circle to another, a left one and a right one. If the points are not on the same diameter than one way will be shorter than the other.

The other trick is that there is a wrap-around at 360° because 360° and 0° are actually the same angle (because, see above – the circle is round).

An example:

the minimum distance between 5° and 355°:

|355 - 5| = 350

but the correct answer would be 10.

If 360° is added to 5:

|355 - 365| = 10

Hence, my simple idea was to check a, a + 360, and a - 360. So, any wrap-around should be covered. There are some distances computed which might be even above of 360 but they will not hurt because the minimum is searched.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int get_dist(int a, int b)
{
  return std::min({ abs(a - b), abs(a + 360 - b), abs(a - 360 - b) });
}

int find_point(int a)
{
  int d11 = get_dist(a, 11);
  int d216 = get_dist(a, 216);
  return d11 < d216 ? 11 : 216;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "20 is closest to " << find_point(20) << '\n';
  std::cout << "200 is closest to " << find_point(200) << '\n';
  std::cout << "350 is closest to " << find_point(350) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
20 is closest to 11
200 is closest to 216
350 is closest to 11
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60ef22d5d74a96c0)

Maybe, not the most elegant but a simple and maintenance-friendly solution (ignoring the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) in the code).

Answer (score 2):

Using some integer magic confined to addition, subtraction, and multiplication:

```c
/* only for systems with 32-bit ints! */
int find_point(int a)
{
        a*=11930465;
        int distance_to_11 = a-131235112;
        int distance_to_216 = a+1717986918;

        if (distance_to_11 > 0) distance_to_11 = -distance_to_11;    // -abs
        if (distance_to_216 > 0) distance_to_216 = -distance_to_216; // -abs

        int nearest;
        if ( distance_to_216 > distance_to_11 ) {
                nearest = 216;
        } else {
                nearest = 11;
        }
        return nearest;
}
```

The essence of this solution is to map the range [-180° ‒ +180°) to the range of a signed 32-bit integer.  Once the mapping is done, one can make use of the natural modulo properties of 2's complement arithmetic.

Note: there is an error introduced in the mapping that will result in incorrect answers for values of `a` that are increasingly beyond the range of 0‒360.  If that is of concern, the value of `a` should be confined to the range 0‒360.

Note: unlike `abs()`, the hand-coded `-abs` ensures a correct result regardless of the input since "*The absolute value of the most negative number cannot be represented in two's complement.*" (see [C11 draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.6.1)).

Derivation of the constants is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Actually, a nice idea but it has a minor flaw: Overflow/underflow of `int` is unfortunately considered as Undefined Behavior. (Not sure why this has been decided. Maybe, one of the compiler producers with vote-right insisted on saving the need for the extra clearing of carry flag which is necessary after overflow/underflow only.) If you would transfer this solution to `unsigned` you could switch to the save side. For `unsigned`, overflow/underflow are well-defined behavior (to result in wrap-around).

Comment: @Scheff very good observation, I keep forgetting `int` is a second-class citizen to `unsigned` when it comes to overflow.  I will revise the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative 'generic' approach that trades modulo arithmetic and additional compares for some simple trig (instead of separate `sin` and `cos`, one could employ `sincos` if available):

```c
#include <math.h>

int find_point(int a)
{
    const double x11 = cos((double)11/180*M_PI);
    const double y11 = sin((double)11/180*M_PI);
    const double x216 = cos((double)216/180*M_PI);
    const double y216 = sin((double)216/180*M_PI);

    double x = cos((double)a/180*M_PI);
    double y = sin((double)a/180*M_PI);

    double square_of_distance_to_11 = (x-x11)*(x-x11) + (y-y11)*(y-y11);
    double square_of_distance_to_216 = (x-x216)*(x-x216) + (y-y216)*(y-y216);

    int nearest;
    if ( square_of_distance_to_216 < square_of_distance_to_11 ) {
        nearest = 216;
    } else {
        nearest = 11;
    }
    return nearest;
}
```

The code is reasonably self-explanatory.  I'm exploiting the property that finding the nearest two points on a circle using the distance *along the circle* is equivalent to finding the nearest two point on a circle using the *straight line* distance between the points.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of modulo and `+`/`-` trickery can avoid the use of `min` or `max` and eliminate the need to compare against additional alias points:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int find_point(int a)
{
        a = (a%360+360)%360;    // clamp 'a' to 0..359
        int distance_to_11 = abs((a-11+180+360)%360-180);
        int distance_to_216 = abs((a-216+180+360)%360-180);

        int nearest;
        if ( distance_to_216 < distance_to_11 ) {
                nearest = 216;
        } else {
                nearest = 11;
        }
        return nearest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is alternate solution.[image: circle] split circle into three parts as shown in picture. when the number is in green region answer is 11 directly, when the number is in yellow region compare between 11 and 216 and when the number is in blue region compare between 216 and ((360-number)+11)

```
int find_point(int a)
```

{

```
if(a>=0&&a<=11)
    return 11;
else if(a>=11&&a<=216)
{
    if((a-11)> (216-a))
        return 216;
    else
        return 11;
}
else if(a>=216&&a<=360)
{
    if((a-216)>(360-a+11))
        return 11;
    else
        return 216;
}
else
    return 0;  //for invalid input
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define min(x,y) ((x)<(y)? (x) : (y))

int circle_dist(int a, int b)
{
    a = (a%360+360)%360;
    b = (b%360+360)%360;
    return min(360-abs(a-b), abs(a-b));
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d (10)\n", circle_dist(10,20));
    printf("%d (10)\n", circle_dist(20,10));

    printf("%d (20)\n", circle_dist(350,10));
    printf("%d (20)\n", circle_dist(10,350));

    printf("%d (180)\n", circle_dist(310,130));
    printf("%d (180)\n", circle_dist(130,310));

    printf("%d (0)\n", circle_dist(1080,360));
    printf("%d (0)\n", circle_dist(0,720));

    return 0;
}
```